# Add SSL Certificate to my domain + AWS DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, dns, amazon-elb

I have a Classic load balancer configured on my AWS webservices at xxx-xxx.amazonaws.com
and have also added route 53 to configure. But it seems there is no traffic moving from my domain to load balancer DNS. Need Help.

On my EC2 Server, I have added a MERN Stack application and used nginx to route the traffic from `:80` to `:8080`. Next, a Elastic IP address is added to ec2 server.
A certificate is created using AWS's ACM and attached to the classic load balancer.
The domain records are handled by AWS's route 53. Domain name is `aamchymumbai.com`.

Thank you!

I did get a fix using CLoudfare.

Another follow up question, I have now. How to can I redirect domain.com to ec2-server.com:8080 and sub-domain.com to ec2-server.com:5000 using nginx + cloudfare?

Comment: Does your domain use the Route53 name servers?

Comment: No, now i'm trying to add SSL using cloudfare. So my domain name is using cloudfare's domain. It got converted from http to https.